# Ext JS JSON Grid Grouping

Tags: json, extjs

I have the following JSON which I need to group inside of a Ext JS 4 Grid:

```
{
root: {
    type: 'viewer',
    people: ['person a', 'person b', 'person c']
},
{
    type: 'editor',
    people: ['person c', 'person d']
}
}
```

I have absolutely no idea where to start to represent this data in an ExtJS Grid.

But, here is what I have so far:

```
var myModel = Ext.create('Ext.data.Model', {
    fields: ['type', 'people']
})

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store' , {
    data: (JSON above),
    model: myModel,
    groupField: 'type',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'root'
        }
    }
});

var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: myStore,
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'people'}
    ]
})

.... other code to display the grid
```

I get a grid to show, but it doesn't group and there isn't any data showing inside of the grid.

For some reason I think I need a more elaborate Model, however, since the "people" object is just an array of strings, I don't know how tell the column definition which dataIndex it is.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a comma `var myGrid = ' <- here`

Comment: Yeah... I had to type this all by hand... There aren't any syntax errors on the actual box this is running. I've fixed it, thanks.

Comment: your json is not valid. isn't root an array of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the grouping feature on the grid.

> This feature allows to display the grid rows aggregated into groups as
>   specified by the Ext.data.Store.groupers specified on the Store. The
>   group will show the title for the group name and then the appropriate
>   records for the group underneath. The groups can also be expanded and
>   collapsed.

- example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/groupgrid.html
- documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping